# Unable to parse a complex json

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to do a drill down navigation app. I have a list of album names. When on click of the album, it will open up a list songs of that specific album. Problem is when i click album, it opens up all the songs of all other albums as well.

Please help. Below are my coding.

Albums JSON:

```
[
    {   "albumid": "1",
        "name":"127 Hours",
        "songs_count":"14"
    },
    {   "albumid": "2",
        "name":"Adele 21",
        "songs_count":"11"
    },
    {   "albumid": "3",
        "name":"Lana Del Rey - Born to Die",
        "songs_count":"12"
    },
    {   "albumid": "4",
        "name":"Once",
        "songs_count":"13"
    },
    {   "albumid": "5",
        "name":"Away We Go",
        "songs_count":"13"
    },
    {   "albumid": "6",
        "name":"Eminem Curtain Call",
        "songs_count":"14"
    },
    {   "albumid": "7",
        "name":"Bad Meets Evil Eminem",
        "songs_count":"11"
    },
    {   "albumid": "8",
        "name":"Safe Trip Home",
        "songs_count":"11"
    },
    {   "albumid": "9",
        "name":"No Angel",
        "songs_count":"12"
    }
]
```

Song List JSON:

```
 [
  {
    "albumid": "1",
    "album": "127 Hours",
    "songs": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Never Hear Surf Music Again",
        "duration": "5:52"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "The Canyon",
        "duration": "3:01"
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Liberation Begins",
        "duration": "2:14"
      },
      {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "Touch of the Sun",
        "duration": "4:39"
      },
      {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "Lovely Day",
        "duration": "4:16"
      },
      {
        "id": "6",
        "name": "Ca Plane Pour Moi",
        "duration": "3:00"
      },
      {
        "id": "7",
        "name": "Liberation In A Dream",
        "duration": "4:06"
      },
      {
        "id": "8",
        "name": "If You Love Me (Really Love Me)",
        "duration": "3:27"
      },
      {
        "id": "9",
        "name": "Acid Darbari",
        "duration": "4:21"
      },
      {
        "id": "10",
        "name": "R.I.P.",
        "duration": "5:11"
      },
      {
        "id": "11",
        "name": "Festival",
        "duration": "9:26"
      },
      {
        "id": "12",
        "name": "If I Rise",
        "duration": "4:38"
      },
      {
        "id": "13",
        "name": "Liberation",
        "duration": "3:11"
      },
      {
        "id": "14",
        "name": "Nocturne No. 2 in E flat",
        "duration": "4:01"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "albumid": "2",
    "album": "Adele 21",
    "songs": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Rolling In The Deep",
        "duration": "03:48"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Rumour Has It",
        "duration": "03:43"
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Turning Tables",
        "duration": "04:10"
      },
      {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "Don\u2019t You Remember",
        "duration": "04:03"
      },
      {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "Set Fire To The Rain",
        "duration": "04:02"
      },
      {
        "id": "6",
        "name": "He Won\u2019t Go",
        "duration": "04:38"
      },
      {
        "id": "7",
        "name": "Take It All",
        "duration": "03:48"
      },
      {
        "id": "8",
        "name": "I\u2019ll Be Waiting",
        "duration": "04:01"
      },
      {
        "id": "9",
        "name": "One And Only",
        "duration": "05:48"
      },
      {
        "id": "10",
        "name": "Lovesong",
        "duration": "05:16"
      },
      {
        "id": "11",
        "name": "Someone Like You",
        "duration": "04:45"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "albumid": "3",
    "album": "Lana Del Rey - Born to Die",
    "songs": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Born to Die",
        "duration": "4:46"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Off to the Races",
        "duration": "5:00"
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Blue Jeans",
        "duration": "3:29"
      },
      {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "Video Games",
        "duration": "4:42"
      },
      {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "Diet Mountain Dew",
        "duration": "3:43"
      },
      {
        "id": "6",
        "name": "National Anthem",
        "duration": "3:51"
      },
      {
        "id": "7",
        "name": "Dark Paradise",
        "duration": "4:03"
      },
      {
        "id": "8",
        "name": "Radio",
        "duration": "3:35"
      },
      {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "Carmen",
        "duration": "4:09"
      },
      {
        "id": "10",
        "name": "Million Dollar Man",
        "duration": "3:50"
      },
      {
        "id": "11",
        "name": "Summertime Sadness",
        "duration": "4:25"
      },
      {
        "id": "12",
        "name": "This Is What Makes Us Girls",
        "duration": "4:00"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "albumid": "4",
    "album": "Once",
    "songs": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Falling Slowly",
        "duration": "4:05"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "If You Want Me",
        "duration": "3:47"
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Broken Hearted Hoover Fixer Sucker Guy",
        "duration": "0:52"
      },
      {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "When Your Mind's Made Up",
        "duration": "3:42"
      },
      {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "Lies",
        "duration": "3:58"
      },
      {
        "id": "6",
        "name": "Gold",
        "duration": "3:59"
      },
      {
        "id": "7",
        "name": "The Hill",
        "duration": "4:34"
      },
      {
        "id": "8",
        "name": "Fallen From The Sky",
        "duration": "3:24"
      },
      {
        "id": "9",
        "name": "Leave",
        "duration": "2:46"
      },
      {
        "id": "10",
        "name": "Trying To Pull Myself Away",
        "duration": "3:35"
      },
      {
        "id": "11",
        "name": "All The Way Down",
        "duration": "2:38"
      },
      {
        "id": "12",
        "name": "Once",
        "duration": "3:37"
      },
      {
        "id": "13",
        "name": "Say It To Me Now",
        "duration": "2:36"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "albumid": "5",
    "album": "Once",
    "songs": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Falling Slowly",
        "duration": "4:05"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "If You Want Me",
        "duration": "3:47"
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Broken Hearted Hoover Fixer Sucker Guy",
        "duration": "0:52"
      },
      {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "When Your Mind's Made Up",
        "duration": "3:42"
      },
      {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "Lies",
        "duration": "3:58"
      },
      {
        "id": "6",
        "name": "Gold",
        "duration": "3:59"
      },
      {
        "id": "7",
        "name": "The Hill",
        "duration": "4:34"
      },
      {
        "id": "8",
        "name": "Fallen From The Sky",
        "duration": "3:24"
      },
      {
        "id": "9",
        "name": "Leave",
        "duration": "2:46"
      },
      {
        "id": "10",
        "name": "Trying To Pull Myself Away",
        "duration": "3:35"
      },
      {
        "id": "11",
        "name": "All The Way Down",
        "duration": "2:38"
      },
      {
        "id": "12",
        "name": "Once",
        "duration": "3:37"
      },
      {
        "id": "13",
        "name": "Say It To Me Now",
        "duration": "2:36"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "albumid": "6",
    "album": "Eminem Curtain Call",
    "songs": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "My Name Is",
        "duration": "4:28"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "The Way I Am",
        "duration": "4:51"
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Lose Yourself",
        "duration": "5:21"
      },
      {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "Shake That",
        "duration": "4:34"
      },
      {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "Sing For The Moment",
        "duration": "5:40"
      },
      {
        "id": "6",
        "name": "Without Me",
        "duration": "4:47"
      },
      {
        "id": "7",
        "name": "Like Toy Soldiers",
        "duration": "4:51"
      },
      {
        "id": "8",
        "name": "The Real Slim Shady",
        "duration": "4:44"
      },
      {
        "id": "9",
        "name": "Mockingbird",
        "duration": "4:11"
      },
      {
        "id": "10",
        "name": "Guilty Conscience",
        "duration": "3:19"
      },
      {
        "id": "11",
        "name": "Cleanin' Out My Closet",
        "duration": "4:58"
      },
      {
        "id": "12",
        "name": "Just Lose It",
        "duration": "4:08"
      },
      {
        "id": "13",
        "name": "When I'm Gone",
        "duration": "4:40"
      },
      {
        "id": "14",
        "name": "Stan",
        "duration": "6:21"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "albumid": "7",
    "album": "Bad Meets Evil Eminem",
    "songs": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Lighters",
        "duration": "5:21"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Fast Lane",
        "duration": "3:19"
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Above the Law",
        "duration": "6:21"
      },
      {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "Welcome 2 Hell",
        "duration": "4:34"
      },
      {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "Take from Me",
        "duration": "4:51"
      },
      {
        "id": "6",
        "name": "The Reunion",
        "duration": "4:44"
      },
      {
        "id": "7",
        "name": "A Kiss",
        "duration": "3:19"
      },
      {
        "id": "8",
        "name": "Echo",
        "duration": "6:21"
      },
      {
        "id": "9",
        "name": "Lighters",
        "duration": "4:40"
      },
      {
        "id": "10",
        "name": "Living Proof",
        "duration": "3:49"
      },
      {
        "id": "11",
        "name": "Loud Noises",
        "duration": "3:19"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "albumid": "8",
    "album": "Safe Trip Home",
    "songs": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Don't Believe in Love",
        "duration": "3:52"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Quiet Times",
        "duration": "3:16"
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Never Want to Say It's Love",
        "duration": "3:34"
      },
      {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "Grafton Street",
        "duration": "5:56"
      },
      {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "It Comes And It Goes",
        "duration": "3:26"
      },
      {
        "id": "6",
        "name": "Look No Further",
        "duration": "3:15"
      },
      {
        "id": "7",
        "name": "Us 2 Little Gods",
        "duration": "4:48"
      },
      {
        "id": "8",
        "name": "The Day Before The Day",
        "duration": "4:12"
      },
      {
        "id": "9",
        "name": "Let's Do the Things We Normally Do",
        "duration": "4:08"
      },
      {
        "id": "10",
        "name": "Burnin Love",
        "duration": "4:10"
      },
      {
        "id": "11",
        "name": "Northern Skies",
        "duration": "8:53"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "albumid": "9",
    "album": "No Angel",
    "songs": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Here With Me",
        "duration": "4:05"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Hunter",
        "duration": "3:55"
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Don't Think Of Me",
        "duration": "4:32"
      },
      {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "My Lover's Gone",
        "duration": "4:27"
      },
      {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "All You Want",
        "duration": "3:53"
      },
      {
        "id": "6",
        "name": "Thank You",
        "duration": "3:36"
      },
      {
        "id": "7",
        "name": "Honestly Ok",
        "duration": "4:37"
      },
      {
        "id": "8",
        "name": "Slide",
        "duration": "4:50"
      },
      {
        "id": "9",
        "name": "Isobel",
        "duration": "3:55"
      },
      {
        "id": "10",
        "name": "I'm No Angel",
        "duration": "3:55"
      },
      {
        "id": "11",
        "name": "My Life",
        "duration": "2:59"
      },
      {
        "id": "12",
        "name": "Take My Hand",
        "duration": "6:50"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

AlbumsActivity.java :

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                // getting JSON string from URL
                String json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_ALBUMS, "GET",
                        params);

                // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
                Log.d("Albums JSON: ", "> " + json);

                try {               
                    albums = new JSONArray(json);

                    if (albums != null) {
                        // looping through All albums
                        for (int i = 0; i < albums.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = albums.getJSONObject(i);

                            // Storing each json item values in variable
                            String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                            String songs_count = c.getString(TAG_SONGS_COUNT);

                            // creating new HashMap
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                            map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                            map.put(TAG_SONGS_COUNT, songs_count);

                            // adding HashList to ArrayList
                            albumsList.add(map);
                        }
                    }else{
                        Log.d("Albums: ", "null");
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }
```

TrackListActivity.java :

```
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            // post album id as GET parameter
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_ALBUM_ID, album_id));

            // getting JSON string from URL
            String json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_ALBUMS, "GET",
                    params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("Track List JSON: ", json);

            try {
                albumtracks = new JSONArray(json);

                if (albumtracks != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < albumtracks.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jObj = albumtracks.getJSONObject(i);
                    String album_id = jObj.getString(TAG_ALBUM_ID);
                    album_name = jObj.getString(TAG_ALBUM);
                    albums = jObj.getJSONArray(TAG_SONGS);

                    if (albums != null) {
                        // looping through All songs
                        for (int j = 0; j < albums.length(); j++) {
                            JSONObject c = albums.getJSONObject(j);

                            // Storing each json item in variable
                            String song_id = c.getString(TAG_SONG_ID);
                            // track no - increment i value
                            String track_no = String.valueOf(j + 1);
                            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                            String duration = c.getString(TAG_DURATION);

                            // creating new HashMap
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            map.put(TAG_ALBUM_ID, album_id);
                            map.put(TAG_SONG_ID, song_id);
                            map.put("track_no", track_no + ".");
                            map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                            map.put(TAG_DURATION, duration);

                            // adding HashList to ArrayList
                            tracksList.add(map);
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.d("Albums: ", "null");
                    }
                }

            }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }
```

FYI, I am hoping I can do this without PHP. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Okay. The reason you haven't got any answers yet (which is unusual for  a JSON question after half an hour) is that no one can be bothered to sift through your code to find the issue. Give us the pieces of code which perform the parsing. Including the JSON is a good start, but you've included whole classes and hundreds of lines of code. We need brevity to help, as our time is precious too

Comment: Could you please post the exception here and possible stacktrace?

Comment: Thx @MattTaylor I've deleted the irrelevant part. Hopefully it is better now.

Comment: @gyan, there is no exception or stacktrace. Read the question

Comment: @user2767579 we'll also need to see the code that displays your albums and songs on screen, as all of the parsing code seems correct

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, looking at your code, I would have thought the best way to construct your app, rather than using a few different maps, is to have a structure:

```
public AlbumListing {

    private String albumTitle
    private String albumArtist
    private HashMap<String, String> trackList = new HashMap<String, String>();

}
```

Which then has getters and setters to create your album. You can then have an `ArrayList` of `AlbumListing`s:

```
ArrayList<AlbumListing> albumList = new ArrayList<AlbumListing>();
```

When you parse the higher-level information (the album title and artist), create the new entry for the first time, and when you parse the lower-level information you can search for the correct Artist's entry, then add the songs to the private hashmap within the entry's `trackList'

Storing your JSON result like this would then keep all of one album's data together, rather than having to sift through two hashmaps to find the songs you need. I have a feeling that if you structure your data like this, the issues you're having with displaying your data will dissolve, as you'll be able to see exactly where the data you want is located.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a library that handles the mapping for you. Jackson, or in the example below, GSON makes this a breeze:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    List<Album> albums = gson.fromJson(albumsJson, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Album>>(){}.getType());

    for (Album album : albums) {
      System.out.println(album);
    }

    List<SongList> songs = gson.fromJson(songListJson, new TypeToken<ArrayList<SongList>>(){}.getType());

    for (SongList song : songs) {
      System.out.println(song);
    }
  }

  class Album {

    @SerializedName("albumid") String albumId;
    String name;
    @SerializedName("songs_count") String songsCount;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "Album{" +
          "albumId='" + albumId + '\'' +
          ", name='" + name + '\'' +
          ", songsCount='" + songsCount + '\'' +
          '}';
    }
  }

  class SongList {

    @SerializedName("albumid") String albumId;
    String album;
    List<Song> songs;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "SongList{" +
          "albumId='" + albumId + '\'' +
          ", album='" + album + '\'' +
          ", songs=" + songs +
          '}';
    }
  }

  class Song {

    String id;
    String name;
    String duration;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "Song{" +
          "id='" + id + '\'' +
          ", name='" + name + '\'' +
          ", duration='" + duration + '\'' +
          '}';
    }
  }

  static String albumsJson = "[\n" +
      "    {   \"albumid\": \"1\",\n" +
      "        \"name\":\"127 Hours\",\n" +
      "        \"songs_count\":\"14\"\n" +
      "    },\n" +
      "    {   \"albumid\": \"2\",\n" +
      "        \"name\":\"Adele 21\",\n" +
      "        \"songs_count\":\"11\"\n" +
      "    },\n" +
      "    {   \"albumid\": \"3\",\n" +
      "        \"name\":\"Lana Del Rey - Born to Die\",\n" +
      "        \"songs_count\":\"12\"\n" +
      "    },\n" +
      "    {   \"albumid\": \"4\",\n" +
      "        \"name\":\"Once\",\n" +
      "        \"songs_count\":\"13\"\n" +
      "    },\n" +
      "    {   \"albumid\": \"5\",\n" +
      "        \"name\":\"Away We Go\",\n" +
      "        \"songs_count\":\"13\"\n" +
      "    },\n" +
      "    {   \"albumid\": \"6\",\n" +
      "        \"name\":\"Eminem Curtain Call\",\n" +
      "        \"songs_count\":\"14\"\n" +
      "    },\n" +
      "    {   \"albumid\": \"7\",\n" +
      "        \"name\":\"Bad Meets Evil Eminem\",\n" +
      "        \"songs_count\":\"11\"\n" +
      "    },\n" +
      "    {   \"albumid\": \"8\",\n" +
      "        \"name\":\"Safe Trip Home\",\n" +
      "        \"songs_count\":\"11\"\n" +
      "    },\n" +
      "    {   \"albumid\": \"9\",\n" +
      "        \"name\":\"No Angel\",\n" +
      "        \"songs_count\":\"12\"\n" +
      "    }\n" +
      "]";

  static String songListJson = "[\n" +
      "  {\n" +
      "    \"albumid\": \"1\",\n" +
      "    \"album\": \"127 Hours\",\n" +
      "    \"songs\": [\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"1\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Never Hear Surf Music Again\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"5:52\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"2\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"The Canyon\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"3:01\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"3\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Liberation Begins\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"2:14\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"4\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Touch of the Sun\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"4:39\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"5\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Lovely Day\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"4:16\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"6\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Ca Plane Pour Moi\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"3:00\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"7\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Liberation In A Dream\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"4:06\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"8\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"If You Love Me (Really Love Me)\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"3:27\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"9\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Acid Darbari\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"4:21\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"10\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"R.I.P.\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"5:11\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"11\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Festival\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"9:26\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"12\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"If I Rise\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"4:38\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"13\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Liberation\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"3:11\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"14\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Nocturne No. 2 in E flat\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"4:01\"\n" +
      "      }\n" +
      "    ]\n" +
      "  },\n" +
      "  {\n" +
      "    \"albumid\": \"2\",\n" +
      "    \"album\": \"Adele 21\",\n" +
      "    \"songs\": [\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"1\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Rolling In The Deep\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"03:48\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"2\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Rumour Has It\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"03:43\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"3\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Turning Tables\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"04:10\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"4\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Don\\u2019t You Remember\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"04:03\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"5\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Set Fire To The Rain\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"04:02\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"6\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"He Won\\u2019t Go\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"04:38\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"7\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Take It All\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"03:48\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"8\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"I\\u2019ll Be Waiting\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"04:01\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"9\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"One And Only\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"05:48\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"10\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Lovesong\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"05:16\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"11\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Someone Like You\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"04:45\"\n" +
      "      }\n" +
      "    ]\n" +
      "  },\n" +
      "  {\n" +
      "    \"albumid\": \"3\",\n" +
      "    \"album\": \"Lana Del Rey - Born to Die\",\n" +
      "    \"songs\": [\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"1\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Born to Die\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"4:46\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"2\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Off to the Races\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"5:00\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"3\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Blue Jeans\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"3:29\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"4\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Video Games\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"4:42\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"5\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Diet Mountain Dew\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"3:43\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"6\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"National Anthem\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"3:51\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"7\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Dark Paradise\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"4:03\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"8\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Radio\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"3:35\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": 9,\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Carmen\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"4:09\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"10\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Million Dollar Man\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"3:50\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"11\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Summertime Sadness\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"4:25\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"12\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"This Is What Makes Us Girls\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"4:00\"\n" +
      "      }\n" +
      "    ]\n" +
      "  },\n" +
      "  {\n" +
      "    \"albumid\": \"4\",\n" +
      "    \"album\": \"Once\",\n" +
      "    \"songs\": [\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"1\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Falling Slowly\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"4:05\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"2\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"If You Want Me\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"3:47\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"3\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Broken Hearted Hoover Fixer Sucker Guy\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"0:52\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"4\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"When Your Mind's Made Up\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"3:42\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"5\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Lies\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"3:58\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"6\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Gold\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"3:59\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"7\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"The Hill\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"4:34\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"8\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Fallen From The Sky\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"3:24\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"9\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Leave\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"2:46\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"10\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Trying To Pull Myself Away\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"3:35\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"11\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"All The Way Down\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"2:38\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"12\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Once\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"3:37\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"13\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Say It To Me Now\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"2:36\"\n" +
      "      }\n" +
      "    ]\n" +
      "  },\n" +
      "  {\n" +
      "    \"albumid\": \"5\",\n" +
      "    \"album\": \"Once\",\n" +
      "    \"songs\": [\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"1\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Falling Slowly\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"4:05\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"2\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"If You Want Me\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"3:47\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"3\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Broken Hearted Hoover Fixer Sucker Guy\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"0:52\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"4\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"When Your Mind's Made Up\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"3:42\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"5\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Lies\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"3:58\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"6\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Gold\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"3:59\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"7\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"The Hill\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"4:34\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"8\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Fallen From The Sky\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"3:24\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"9\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Leave\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"2:46\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"10\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Trying To Pull Myself Away\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"3:35\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"11\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"All The Way Down\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"2:38\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"12\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Once\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"3:37\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"13\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Say It To Me Now\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"2:36\"\n" +
      "      }\n" +
      "    ]\n" +
      "  },\n" +
      "  {\n" +
      "    \"albumid\": \"6\",\n" +
      "    \"album\": \"Eminem Curtain Call\",\n" +
      "    \"songs\": [\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"1\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"My Name Is\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"4:28\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"2\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"The Way I Am\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"4:51\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"3\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Lose Yourself\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"5:21\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"4\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Shake That\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"4:34\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"5\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Sing For The Moment\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"5:40\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"6\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Without Me\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"4:47\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"7\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Like Toy Soldiers\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"4:51\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"8\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"The Real Slim Shady\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"4:44\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"9\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Mockingbird\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"4:11\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"10\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Guilty Conscience\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"3:19\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"11\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Cleanin' Out My Closet\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"4:58\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"12\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Just Lose It\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"4:08\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"13\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"When I'm Gone\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"4:40\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"14\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Stan\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"6:21\"\n" +
      "      }\n" +
      "    ]\n" +
      "  },\n" +
      "  {\n" +
      "    \"albumid\": \"7\",\n" +
      "    \"album\": \"Bad Meets Evil Eminem\",\n" +
      "    \"songs\": [\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"1\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Lighters\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"5:21\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"2\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Fast Lane\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"3:19\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"3\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Above the Law\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"6:21\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"4\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Welcome 2 Hell\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"4:34\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"5\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Take from Me\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"4:51\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"6\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"The Reunion\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"4:44\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"7\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"A Kiss\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"3:19\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"8\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Echo\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"6:21\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"9\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Lighters\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"4:40\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"10\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Living Proof\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"3:49\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"11\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Loud Noises\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"3:19\"\n" +
      "      }\n" +
      "    ]\n" +
      "  },\n" +
      "  {\n" +
      "    \"albumid\": \"8\",\n" +
      "    \"album\": \"Safe Trip Home\",\n" +
      "    \"songs\": [\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"1\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Don't Believe in Love\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"3:52\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"2\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Quiet Times\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"3:16\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"3\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Never Want to Say It's Love\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"3:34\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"4\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Grafton Street\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"5:56\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"5\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"It Comes And It Goes\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"3:26\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"6\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Look No Further\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"3:15\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"7\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Us 2 Little Gods\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"4:48\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"8\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"The Day Before The Day\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"4:12\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"9\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Let's Do the Things We Normally Do\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"4:08\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"10\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Burnin Love\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"4:10\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"11\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Northern Skies\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"8:53\"\n" +
      "      }\n" +
      "    ]\n" +
      "  },\n" +
      "  {\n" +
      "    \"albumid\": \"9\",\n" +
      "    \"album\": \"No Angel\",\n" +
      "    \"songs\": [\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"1\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Here With Me\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"4:05\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"2\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Hunter\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"3:55\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"3\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Don't Think Of Me\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"4:32\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"4\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"My Lover's Gone\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"4:27\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"5\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"All You Want\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"3:53\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"6\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Thank You\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"3:36\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"7\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Honestly Ok\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"4:37\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"8\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Slide\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"4:50\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"9\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Isobel\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"3:55\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"10\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"I'm No Angel\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"3:55\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"11\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"My Life\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"2:59\"\n" +
      "      },\n" +
      "      {\n" +
      "        \"id\": \"12\",\n" +
      "        \"name\": \"Take My Hand\",\n" +
      "        \"duration\": \"6:50\"\n" +
      "      }\n" +
      "    ]\n" +
      "  }\n" +
      "]";
}
```

Running this `Main` class produces:

```
Album{albumId='1', name='127 Hours', songsCount='14'}
Album{albumId='2', name='Adele 21', songsCount='11'}
Album{albumId='3', name='Lana Del Rey - Born to Die', songsCount='12'}
Album{albumId='4', name='Once', songsCount='13'}
Album{albumId='5', name='Away We Go', songsCount='13'}
Album{albumId='6', name='Eminem Curtain Call', songsCount='14'}
Album{albumId='7', name='Bad Meets Evil Eminem', songsCount='11'}
Album{albumId='8', name='Safe Trip Home', songsCount='11'}
Album{albumId='9', name='No Angel', songsCount='12'}
SongList{albumId='1', album='127 Hours', songs=[Song{id='1', name='Never Hear Surf Music Again', duration='5:52'}, Song{id='2', name='The Canyon', duration='3:01'}, Song{id='3', name='Liberation Begins', duration='2:14'}, Song{id='4', name='Touch of the Sun', duration='4:39'}, Song{id='5', name='Lovely Day', duration='4:16'}, Song{id='6', name='Ca Plane Pour Moi', duration='3:00'}, Song{id='7', name='Liberation In A Dream', duration='4:06'}, Song{id='8', name='If You Love Me (Really Love Me)', duration='3:27'}, Song{id='9', name='Acid Darbari', duration='4:21'}, Song{id='10', name='R.I.P.', duration='5:11'}, Song{id='11', name='Festival', duration='9:26'}, Song{id='12', name='If I Rise', duration='4:38'}, Song{id='13', name='Liberation', duration='3:11'}, Song{id='14', name='Nocturne No. 2 in E flat', duration='4:01'}]}
SongList{albumId='2', album='Adele 21', songs=[Song{id='1', name='Rolling In The Deep', duration='03:48'}, Song{id='2', name='Rumour Has It', duration='03:43'}, Song{id='3', name='Turning Tables', duration='04:10'}, Song{id='4', name='Don’t You Remember', duration='04:03'}, Song{id='5', name='Set Fire To The Rain', duration='04:02'}, Song{id='6', name='He Won’t Go', duration='04:38'}, Song{id='7', name='Take It All', duration='03:48'}, Song{id='8', name='I’ll Be Waiting', duration='04:01'}, Song{id='9', name='One And Only', duration='05:48'}, Song{id='10', name='Lovesong', duration='05:16'}, Song{id='11', name='Someone Like You', duration='04:45'}]}
SongList{albumId='3', album='Lana Del Rey - Born to Die', songs=[Song{id='1', name='Born to Die', duration='4:46'}, Song{id='2', name='Off to the Races', duration='5:00'}, Song{id='3', name='Blue Jeans', duration='3:29'}, Song{id='4', name='Video Games', duration='4:42'}, Song{id='5', name='Diet Mountain Dew', duration='3:43'}, Song{id='6', name='National Anthem', duration='3:51'}, Song{id='7', name='Dark Paradise', duration='4:03'}, Song{id='8', name='Radio', duration='3:35'}, Song{id='9', name='Carmen', duration='4:09'}, Song{id='10', name='Million Dollar Man', duration='3:50'}, Song{id='11', name='Summertime Sadness', duration='4:25'}, Song{id='12', name='This Is What Makes Us Girls', duration='4:00'}]}
...
```